# INSERT INTO not functioning as should

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

I have an error with my insert into line, it's about this bad boy

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts('username', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email') 
VALUES($username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $email)") 
or die("Could not create account! <br/>" . mysql_error());
```

the error I am supplied with is the following:

> Could not create account!
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email') VALUES(test, test,' at line 1

I suspect it has something to do with the variables not being called correctly?

Comment: Please read one of the other 37489379 answers about this problem ASAP.

Comment: You need to quote the values you're adding with single quotes. `'$username'`, and so on. Though you might also want to look at using PDO and making this into a prepared statement, as it's easier to write and much more secure.

Comment: You don't quote the column names as you have done after `accounts(...)`

Comment: Aren't the `mysql_*` functions considered as a bad practice?

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of problems, so I'll summarize them:

- `INSERT INTO t1 ('col'` -- note that `'col'` is wrapped in quotes.  This means that it attempts to insert into the string literal "col1" rather than the column name.  Remove the quotes and replace them with backticks (or nothing)
- The values themselves are not wrapped in quotes.  You have `VALUES(test` -- this semantically means insert the value of column "test," which makes no sense.  You actually need to wrap this one in quotes.
- I'd venture to guess that none of the input parameters are properly escaped.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I was typing out an answer, but you beat me to it.  The OP's main problem is the quotes in the wrong places.  The solution is to forget about "mysql_query()" and instead use PDO or [mysqli] with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

My friend the fields in the querys shouldn't be quoted. Try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES($username, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $email)") or die("Could not create account!" . mysql_error());
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use quotes `'` in the query but backtick `

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `accounts` (`username`, `password`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."','". $firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$email."')") or die("Could not create account! " . mysql_error())
```

[**insert into documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

I would like to also to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query is not recommended, soon to be deprecated. Probably best to use PDO or mysqli instead.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

But to answer your question, I believe it's because your column names are in single quotes(rather than backticks).

It's your *values* that need to be within single-quotes. You'll probably want to run mysql_real_escape_string on those variables too, to prevent SQL injection. Or just use PDO prepared statements instead.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php